# weird behaviour when comparing

Tags: php

Can anyone explain why this is happening,

```
<?php
if (0 == 'fasas')// or if ('fasas' == 0)
{
  exit('if condition success');
}
exit;
```

**Output** : **`if condition success`**

**Here I am checking a string equivalent to zero and it always success I can't understand this behavior**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [string conversion to numbers in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

So:

```
if ('fasas' == 0) {
    echo 'This is true, fasas has no numbers so it is converted to 0';
}

if ('0fasas' == 0) {
    echo 'This is true also, 0fasas is converted to 0';
}

if ('1fasas' == 0) {
    echo 'This is false, 1fasas is converted to 1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `===` which is a strict comparison, meaning both value and type are being compared.

Simply using `==` is not strict, meaning that comparing a string to 0 will also be true.

```
if ('fasas' === 0)
{
  exit('if condition success');
}
exit;
```

You can also use [strcmp()](https://www.php.net/strcmp), which is a safe binary comparison.

[This is an interesting blog about it](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know that but my question is `if ('' == 0)
{
  exit('if condition success');
}
exit;` will this output `if condition success`

Comment: if ('any string' == 0) will ALWAYS BE TRUE. if ('any string' === 0) will always be false, even if ('0' === 0)

Comment: I know that but usually when we compare it should check equivalent that's what many frameworks does thanx

Comment: Yes, PHP handles comparison differently than other languages. Did that answer your question though?